# Multiple requests asking for oAuth Token at the same time (Requests going From PHP to Java(Spring))

Tags: spring, magento2, php-7, oauth-1.0a

How to handle the way of getting oAuth Tokens when Multiple users use the application simultaneouslu\y(Requests going From PHP to Java(Spring))

Comment: what do yuo mean?

Comment: @AngeloImmediata Hi, Am using REST web service and am trying to get access token when multiple users use application simultaneously. This creates "Invalid token" issue for all the users since they are using system simultaneously

Comment: Maybe you should make your method thread-safe by synchronization